# Show Dynamic Data in Tooltip

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to show dynamic data in tooltip
i need something like this website

```
www.mcxindia.com
```

this website have a scrolling ticker
whenever you hover on any stock it shows the regarding data in tooltip

i want to do something like this on

```
www.mastertrade.in
```

can anytell me how to do that

i know that can be done by ajax
want some help with the coding

Comment: you need to use AJAX for that. I think no one is going to provide the complete code. There are a lot of tutorials on the web regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you in implementing AJAX tool tips:
http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

Comment: thanks

but that can be achieved from AJAX TICKER from Dynamic Drive

Comment: definitely jQuery one has got more options and theming options but really it's up to you whichever one you wanna use :/